# How to understand top and htop results for tomcat with java threads

Tags: java, linux, tomcat, htop, top-command

Using `htop` and `atop` commands show that Java eats much CPU. Here are `htop` results:

[image].

As I understood, the main Tomcat thread with PID=17649 takes 248% of all CPUs. And then other java threads created inside app take small amount of CPU like 4-3%

But when I run `top -H -p 17649`, then I see:

[image]

And there isn't any java thread with high CPU usage.

My questions are:

1. How to find LWP (light process id) to map it to `jstack` output?
2. Do `htop` results mean that all CPU uses by Tomcat itself?
3. Why `atop` or `ps -eLo pid,lwp,pcpu,vsz|grep  17649 |sort -n -k 3 -r |head -n 10` doesn't show thread with high CPU usage?

Thanks.

Comment: I don't think "top -H" shows all threads by default, when run in interactive mode, although I guess it might be possible to make it do so. Still, it's possible that you're not seeing the thread with high CPU because it's simply not on screen. Perhaps try "top -H -p XXX -b -n 1". On Linux, the "nid" attribute in jstack should correspond to the process ID.